# Getting a group of specific entries from a data frame

Tags: r, lapply

I have a data frame with a column `row` with row indexes and a column `col` with column indexes.

```
indexes_df <- structure(list(row = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 8L, 11L, 12L, 8L, 8L, 
5L, 8L, 8L, 16L, 8L, 16L, 8L, 8L, 16L, 5L, 8L, 16L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 
14L, 15L, 16L, 15L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 15L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 
6L, 8L, 10L, 13L, 15L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 13L, 15L, 1L, 
2L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 13L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 10L, 13L, 15L, 2L, 5L, 
6L, 8L, 10L, 13L, 15L), col = c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 
25L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 53L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
100L, 100L, 100L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 108L, 
109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 109L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 
112L, 112L, 112L, 121L, 121L, 121L, 121L, 121L, 121L, 121L, 121L, 
128L, 128L, 128L, 128L, 128L, 128L, 128L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-87L))
```

These indexes belong to ("suspicious") entries in another data frame (see below). I would like to find a way to for each column, to get the entries for the row numbers and put them in a table or data frame.

So for example, column 25 is `Incub_25`. There are issues in row 5, 8 and 16. I would like to fetch `[5,25], [8,25] and [16,25]` and put those entries under `Incub_25`

```
Incub_25
9
10
2
```

I am trying to think of a way to write the syntax to do this. I would first have to create columns from all the unique values in `col`, and then put each entry below.

But I am coming up short. Could someone help me make a start with how to do this?

## DPUT target_df

**Please note that for some reason the `dput` below does not work for me, [but I checked with a third person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74399169/storing-dput-fails?noredirect=1#comment131340910_74399169) who could run the `dput` without issue.**

```
target_df <- structure(list(Incub_1 = c(0.385196293090574, 1.11942931199418, 
0.204807262758973, -0.658873075589505, -1.23526854978509, 0.304188863339875, 
1.9624144441043, -0.964648271693746, 0.326228882549623, 0.882659575810153, 
-0.876661591947629, 0.620359344297636, -0.757983464647292, 1.12239728977615, 
1.71009398297967, -1.58696927045269), Incub_2 = c(-0.0414632979748666, 
0.296547049458993, 1.71909288891566, 0.518769534446091, -0.624908719260206, 
0.601262573635932, 0.469909085365189, -0.664675254364598, -0.440454285558811, 
-1.07950749999069, 1.0059842309736, 1.08189298333815, -0.667124626455829, 
-0.423829554001461, 0.00150373558190289, 1.88126771405575), Incub_3 = c(0.793991364919319, 
1.20307801797634, -0.0737930243600645, 0.523966041771911, 1.69422525823244, 
0.453199056517207, 0.353528213847739, -0.735489729202925, -1.36597876954093, 
1.80789040434975, -0.789466064046612, -0.324545723958204, -2.44569102445658, 
-0.500861487189826, -0.493791835935263, 1.68043918952518), Incub_4 = c(-1.18020105490573, 
-1.08512266252087, 1.97879923168689, 1.1306583336137, 1.14412583281056, 
1.38508255909683, 1.18664910668881, -0.256958141033041, -0.29050820311122, 
-0.59216215209202, 1.71637902072828, 1.14829900721385, -0.479138994377477, 
-0.438553465256564, -0.119020860341265, -0.031698340453245), 
    Incub_5 = c(-0.20304078968779, -0.357916799052825, 0.17277250945184, 
    -0.246603798203555, -0.849815214014788, 2.24197498853988, 
    -0.838647918810149, -1.2043883385906, -1.57422933887106, 
    0.876993752725877, 1.03498477948996, 0.302085601261494, 0.434192568904241, 
    -1.12092791465893, 0.396233192639553, -0.989552665811105), 
    Incub_6 = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 
    1, 1, 1, 1), label = NA, class = c("labelled", "numeric")), 
    Incub_7 = structure(c(1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 
    3, 4, 3, 2), label = NA, class = c("labelled", "numeric")), 
    Incub_8 = structure(c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), levels = character(0), class = c("labelled", 
    "factor"), label = NA), Incub_9 = structure(c(12, 18, 65, 
    20, 10, 20, 22, 300, 16, 9, 23, 40, 9, 25, 12, 7), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_10 = structure(c(8, 7, 16, 10, 6, 10, 
    12, 175, 8, 6, 17, 26, 4, 11, 8, 4), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_11 = structure(c(3, 17, 47, 10, 5, 17, 
    5, 100, 16, 2, 16, 20, 6, 24, 10, 5), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_12 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_13 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, NA, 2, 2, NA, NA, 2, 2, 2, 2), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_14 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 3, 3, NA, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_15 = structure(c(NA, NA, 4, NA, NA, 4, 
    NA, NA, 4, NA, NA, NA, 4, 4, NA, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_16 = structure(c(NA, 5, NA, 5, 5, NA, 
    NA, NA, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_17 = structure(c(3, NA, 6, NA, NA, 2, 
    NA, 1, NA, NA, 4, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_18 = structure(c(NA, 7, 2, 250, 5, 0, 
    0, NA, NA, 10, NA, 150, 22, 27, 2, 650), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_19 = structure(c(NA, 4, 0, 100, NA, 0, 
    0, NA, NA, 9, NA, 40, 5, 27, 0, 350), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_20 = structure(c(NA, 7, 1, 4, 8, 1, 1, 
    9, NA, 2, NA, 3, 7, 5, 1, 6), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_21 = structure(c(NA, 5, 1, 4, NA, 1, 1, 
    9, NA, 8, NA, 7, 2, 3, 2, 6), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_22 = structure(c(NA, 6, 2, 4, NA, 1, 1, 
    10, NA, 7, NA, 9, 1, 3, 5, 8), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_23 = structure(c(0, 11, 1, 175, 4, 0, 
    5, NA, NA, 15, NA, 65, 3, 97, 1, 1175), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_24 = structure(c(NA, 7, 1, 9, NA, 1, 4, 
    10, NA, 3, NA, 5, 2, 6, 1, 8), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_25 = structure(c(NA, 7, 1, 8, 9, 1, 5, 
    10, NA, 3, NA, 6, 1, 4, 1, 2), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_26 = structure(c(0, 5, 0, 175, 1, 0, 1, 
    0, NA, 9, NA, 25, 0, 27, 0, 650), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_27 = structure(c(6, 5, 6, 4, 1, 1, 5, 
    6, NA, 5, NA, 5, 1, 5, 6, 5), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_28 = structure(c(NA, 3, 0, 80, 2, 0, 1, 
    NA, NA, 15, NA, 25, 2, 27, 0, 1175), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_29 = structure(c(NA, 4, 6, 3, 2, 6, 5, 
    6, NA, 5, NA, 4, 1, 5, 6, 4), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_30 = structure(c(0, 5, 2, NA, 6, NA, 1, 
    NA, NA, 14, NA, 25, 1, 27, 1, 600), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_31 = structure(c(NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_32 = structure(c(NA, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_33 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_34 = structure(c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), levels = character(0), class = c("labelled", 
    "factor"), label = NA), Incub_35 = structure(c(7, 3, 2, 4, 
    2, 7, 5, 7, NA, 5, NA, 5, 1, 3, 1, 4), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_36 = structure(c(1, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 
    7, NA, 6, NA, 6, 3, 5, 5, 4), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_37 = structure(c(0, 6, 0, 80, 1, 0, 2, 
    NA, NA, 2, NA, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_38 = structure(c(NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_39 = structure(c(NA, 2, NA, NA, 2, NA, 
    2, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_40 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, NA, 
    3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_41 = structure(c(NA, 4, NA, NA, 4, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_42 = structure(c(NA, NA, 5, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, NA, NA, NA, 5), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_43 = structure(c(3, NA, NA, 4, NA, 2, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 6, 5), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_44 = structure(c(4, 5, 2, 5, 5, 5, 4, 
    5, NA, 5, NA, 1, 4, 5, 3, 5), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_45 = structure(c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), levels = character(0), class = c("labelled", 
    "factor"), label = NA), Incub_46 = structure(c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), levels = character(0), class = c("labelled", "factor"), label = NA), 
    Incub_47 = structure(c(NA, NA, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_48 = structure(c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), levels = character(0), class = c("labelled", 
    "factor"), label = NA), Incub_49 = structure(c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), levels = character(0), class = c("labelled", "factor"), label = NA), 
    Incub_50 = structure(c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), levels = character(0), class = c("labelled", 
    "factor"), label = NA), Incub_51 = structure(c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), levels = character(0), class = c("labelled", "factor"), label = NA), 
    Incub_52 = structure(c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), levels = character(0), class = c("labelled", 
    "factor"), label = NA), Incub_53 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_54 = structure(c(5, 5, NA, NA, 5, 5, 3, 
    3, NA, 5, NA, NA, 3, 5, 4, 5), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_55 = structure(c(1, 2, NA, NA, NA, 2, 
    3, 2, NA, 1, NA, NA, 3, 1, NA, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_56 = structure(c(5, 3, NA, NA, NA, 4, 
    7, 4, NA, 5, NA, NA, 3, 5, NA, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_57 = structure(c(5, 7, NA, NA, 4, 5, 4, 
    4, NA, 5, NA, NA, 3, 5, 2, 2), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_58 = structure(c(1, 6, NA, NA, NA, 2, 
    3, 2, NA, 1, NA, NA, 3, 1, NA, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_59 = structure(c(5, 7, NA, NA, NA, 4, 
    7, 3, NA, 5, NA, NA, 3, 5, NA, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_60 = structure(c(7, 2, NA, NA, 4, 7, 1, 
    3, NA, 4, NA, NA, 2, 3, 5, 2), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_61 = structure(c(6, 3, NA, NA, NA, 6, 
    3, 2, NA, 3, NA, NA, 2, 3, NA, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_62 = structure(c(7, 1, NA, NA, NA, 7, 
    7, 3, NA, 4, NA, NA, 4, 3, NA, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_63 = structure(c(3, 5, NA, NA, 5, 3, 4, 
    2, NA, 4, NA, NA, 4, 5, 3, 5), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_64 = structure(c(3, 2, NA, NA, NA, 3, 
    3, 2, NA, 1, NA, NA, 2, 1, NA, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_65 = structure(c(4, 3, NA, NA, NA, 3, 
    7, 3, NA, 4, NA, NA, 4, 5, NA, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_66 = structure(c(3, 5, NA, NA, 5, 3, 4, 
    4, NA, 5, NA, NA, 3, 5, 5, 5), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_67 = structure(c(2, 2, NA, NA, NA, 2, 
    3, 2, NA, 2, NA, NA, 3, 1, NA, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_68 = structure(c(4, 3, NA, NA, NA, 4, 
    7, 4, NA, 4, NA, NA, 2, 5, NA, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_69 = structure(c(5, 5, NA, NA, 4, 2, 3, 
    5, NA, 4, NA, NA, 5, 4, 5, 5), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_70 = structure(c(2, 2, NA, NA, NA, 1, 
    1, 2, NA, 3, NA, NA, 2, 2, NA, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_71 = structure(c(4, 3, NA, NA, NA, 3, 
    7, 4, NA, 3, NA, NA, 4, 4, NA, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_72 = structure(c(4, 5, NA, NA, 5, 2, 5, 
    5, NA, 4, NA, NA, 3, 5, 4, 5), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_73 = structure(c(2, 2, NA, NA, NA, 2, 
    3, 2, NA, 1, NA, NA, 3, 1, NA, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_74 = structure(c(4, 3, NA, NA, NA, 3, 
    7, 3, NA, 4, NA, NA, 2, 5, NA, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_75 = structure(c(4, 5, NA, NA, 4, 3, 3, 
    5, NA, 5, NA, NA, 4, 5, 5, 5), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_76 = structure(c(2, 2, NA, NA, NA, 2, 
    3, 2, NA, 1, NA, NA, 2, 1, NA, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_77 = structure(c(4, 4, NA, NA, NA, 3, 
    7, 2, NA, 5, NA, NA, 5, 5, NA, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_78 = structure(c(3, 3, NA, NA, 4, 3, 2, 
    1, NA, 4, NA, NA, 2, 2, 2, 5), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_79 = structure(c(3, 2, NA, NA, NA, 2, 
    3, 2, NA, 2, NA, NA, 3, 3, NA, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_80 = structure(c(3, 5, NA, NA, NA, 3, 
    7, 3, NA, 3, NA, NA, 2, 3, NA, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_81 = structure(c(4, 5, NA, NA, 4, 3, 3, 
    5, NA, 5, NA, NA, 5, 5, 4, 4), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_82 = structure(c(2, 2, NA, NA, NA, 2, 
    3, 2, NA, 3, NA, NA, 1, 1, NA, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_83 = structure(c(4, 3, NA, NA, NA, 3, 
    7, 2, NA, 3, NA, NA, 5, 5, NA, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_84 = structure(c(3, 4, NA, NA, 5, 3, 5, 
    4, NA, 5, NA, NA, 4, 5, 5, 5), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_85 = structure(c(3, 2, NA, NA, NA, 2, 
    3, 2, NA, 1, NA, NA, 2, 1, NA, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_86 = structure(c(3, 4, NA, NA, NA, 3, 
    7, 2, NA, 4, NA, NA, 3, 5, NA, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_87 = structure(c(3, 7, NA, NA, 5, 3, 3, 
    3, NA, 4, NA, NA, 7, 3, 2, 5), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_88 = structure(c(3, 6, NA, NA, NA, 2, 
    3, 2, NA, 3, NA, NA, 6, 2, NA, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_89 = structure(c(3, 7, NA, NA, NA, 3, 
    7, 2, NA, 3, NA, NA, 7, 3, NA, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_90 = structure(c(7, 4, NA, NA, 5, 3, 4, 
    3, NA, 5, NA, NA, 5, 5, 4, 4), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_91 = structure(c(6, 2, NA, NA, NA, 2, 
    3, 2, NA, 1, NA, NA, 2, 1, NA, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_92 = structure(c(7, 2, NA, NA, NA, 3, 
    7, 3, NA, 4, NA, NA, 4, 5, NA, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_93 = structure(c(3, 5, NA, NA, 4, 3, 5, 
    5, NA, 5, NA, NA, 4, 5, 5, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_94 = structure(c(3, 2, NA, NA, NA, 2, 
    3, 2, NA, 3, NA, NA, 2, 3, NA, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_95 = structure(c(3, 3, NA, NA, NA, 3, 
    7, 4, NA, 3, NA, NA, 4, 4, NA, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_96 = structure(c(4, 4, NA, NA, 4, 3, 4, 
    5, NA, 5, NA, NA, 4, 5, 4, 5), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_97 = structure(c(2, 2, NA, NA, NA, 2, 
    3, 1, NA, 2, NA, NA, 2, 1, NA, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_98 = structure(c(4, 3, NA, NA, NA, 3, 
    7, 4, NA, 3, NA, NA, 3, 3, NA, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_99 = structure(c(5, 5, NA, 1, 3, 3, 1, 
    3, NA, 3, NA, NA, 2, 5, 4, 5), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_100 = structure(c(6, 1, NA, NA, 7, 3, 
    NA, 2, NA, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_101 = structure(c(5, 4, NA, NA, 3, 2, 
    NA, 4, NA, 4, NA, NA, NA, 3, 4, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_102 = structure(c(4, 5, NA, 5, 4, 4, 5, 
    5, NA, 5, NA, NA, 3, 5, 4, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_103 = structure(c(4, 5, NA, 5, 1, 4, 5, 
    5, NA, 5, NA, NA, 5, 5, 4, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_104 = structure(c(3, 5, NA, 4, 4, 2, 1, 
    4, NA, 5, NA, NA, 3, 3, 4, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_105 = structure(c(4, 5, NA, 5, 3, 4, 4, 
    4, NA, 5, NA, NA, 5, 5, 5, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_106 = structure(c(5, 5, NA, 4, 2, 4, 4, 
    4, NA, 5, NA, NA, 5, 5, 5, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_107 = structure(c(5, 5, NA, 4, 2, 4, 4, 
    4, NA, 5, NA, NA, 5, 5, 5, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_108 = structure(c(7, 3, NA, NA, 8, 1, 
    NA, 2, NA, 6, NA, NA, 4, NA, 5, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_109 = structure(c(4, NA, NA, NA, 8, 2, 
    7, 6, NA, 5, NA, NA, 3, NA, 1, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_110 = structure(c(1, 5, NA, 3, 1, 1, 4, 
    3, NA, 5, NA, NA, 5, 5, 5, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_111 = structure(c(4, 4, NA, 1, 3, 2, 3, 
    4, NA, 1, NA, NA, 4, 5, 1, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_112 = structure(c(5, 1, NA, NA, 4, NA, 
    2, 6, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, NA, NA, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_113 = structure(c(3, 4, NA, NA, 1, NA, 
    1, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 5, NA, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_114 = structure(c(1, 1, NA, 1, NA, 1, 
    1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_115 = structure(c(NA, 2, NA, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_116 = structure(c(NA, 3, NA, NA, 3, 3, 
    3, 3, NA, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_117 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 4, 
    NA, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 4, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_118 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, 5, 
    5, 5, NA, 5, NA, NA, 5, 5, NA, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_119 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 6, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_120 = structure(c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), levels = character(0), class = c("labelled", 
    "factor"), label = NA), Incub_121 = structure(c(6, NA, NA, 
    NA, 7, 4, 1, 2, NA, 3, NA, NA, 5, NA, 8, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_122 = structure(c(4, 2, NA, 2, 5, 1, 3, 
    5, NA, 5, NA, NA, 5, 5, 5, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_123 = structure(c(3, 5, NA, 2, 5, 2, 2, 
    5, NA, 5, NA, NA, 4, 3, 5, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_124 = structure(c(3, 4, NA, 2, 5, 2, 3, 
    3, NA, 5, NA, NA, 4, 3, 4, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_125 = structure(c(4, 2, NA, 2, 5, 1, 3, 
    5, NA, 5, NA, NA, 5, 5, 5, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_126 = structure(c(4, 5, NA, 2, 5, 2, 4, 
    5, NA, 4, NA, NA, 5, 5, 5, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_127 = structure(c(4, 5, NA, 2, 5, 1, 4, 
    5, NA, 5, NA, NA, 5, 5, 5, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric")), Incub_128 = structure(c(NA, 5, NA, NA, 6, 3, 
    NA, 2, NA, 1, NA, NA, 7, NA, 4, NA), label = NA, class = c("labelled", 
    "numeric"))), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that one might work:

```
tcols <- unique(indexes_df$col)
tcols <- set_names(tcols, colnames(target_df)[tcols])

ret <- map(tcols, ~ {
    trows <- indexes_df %>% filter(col == .x) %>% pull(row)
    target_df %>% 
         mutate("row"=row_number()) %>% 
         select(row, all_of(.x)) %>% 
         filter(row_number() %in% trows)
})
```

`ret$Incub_25` gives

```
 │row  │Incub_25
1│    5│       9
2│    8│      10
3│   16│       2
```

Some explanations: I create the tcols (target cols) as a named vector because you would like to have the results named by column names.

In the map function, I first select only the rows of `indexes_df` which correspond to the given column (which is the value of tcols) and pull them out as a vector called trows.

Then, I take target_df, add row numbers (just to be able to double check the results, you can remove it), select both the column row and the column .x (the given value of tcols), and finally keep only row numbers which were are in trows.

Or, simpler, if you do not want to keep the row numbers:

```
ret <- map(tcols, ~ {
    trows <- indexes_df %>% filter(col == .x) %>% pull(row)
    target_df[ trows, .x, drop=F]
})
```

You can also use the non-tidyverse version:

```
tcols <- unique(indexes_df$col)
names(tcols) <- colnames(target_df)[tcols]

ret <- lapply(tcols, \(x) {
   trows <- indexes_df$row[ indexes_df$col == x ]
   target_df[ trows, x, drop=F]
})
```

Comment: Do you know how I can make a data frame out of the second `ret` (the one without row numbers). I tried `df <- cbind(ret)`, but that does not work correctly. I also tried `cbind.data.frame(ret)`, but it does not accept different row numbers.

Comment: What are you trying to do? These data frames in `ret` have different numbers of rows, you can't just combine them with cbind. For the `ret` with row numbers, you could use `merge`  with parameters `by="row", all=TRUE`, or `full_join()`. And generally, if you want somehow to put together elements of a list, you can use the function `Reduce`, e.g. `Reduce(cbind, ret)` (will not work though with different row numbers).